# QGIS 3.4 crashing when loading two different files with different coordinate systems

Tags: qgis

I'm having trouble loading some files in QGIS 3.45 "Madiera". I have a CSV loading as WGS84, and a BMP loading in as UTM 12N NAD 83. Both the files load fine individually but as soon as they are loaded in the same map, it crashes. I've done the same thing in QGIS 2.18 and it works perfectly fine.

I've tried setting the project CRS to both of the CRS and it hasn't worked.

Comment: What happen if you load one layer and reproject it to the other CRS?

Answer (score 1):

Well I figured it out. I was accidentally using the WGS 84 in the 'geocentric coordinate systems'.

Point of advice: don't do this.